# Is there an indicator of total index fragmentation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-indexes

I use `IndexOptimize` from [ola.hallengren.com](https://ola.hallengren.com) to maintain my indexes.

I schedule a weekly execution of `IndexOptimize` to have good performances, moreover on an Admin form of my application i added a button "Optimize indexes now". This will call `IndexOptimize`.

After this is run I would like to show to the user an indicator of the current situation.

The simplest thing I found is showing averages from the index physical stats table:

```
SELECT
AVG(avg_fragmentation_in_percent) as OverallFragmentationIndicator
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

The idea is to show the indicator before and after the operation to let the user "see some improvement".
Do you know a more realiable approach?

Comment: What is unreliable about this query? You might improve it by showing the fragmentation by table. Wouldn't you just want to schedule this job to run automatically at off hours though? I don't know that I would want to worry about this in an application. And the users would need to know that running this during business hours could be a huge performance hit.

Comment: More reliable would be having a way to actually measure the performance characteristics of your queries and compare those, like Query Store does (or attempts, anyway). What's the point of coming up with a number for index fragmentation if you don't even know what the actual, measurable impact of that is? You could go from 99 to 1 and notice nothing, or you could go from 50 to 48 and have a very real difference. Having a button for it could be nothing more than a placebo, except that pushing it would not be a free action.

Comment: Actually I thought of one "issue". Ola's scripts don't fix heap fragmentation, which could throw off your numbers if you have a lot of unindexed tables.

Comment: Thaks to all of you. In fact in my applciation realy rarely i saw an improvement from rebuilding indexes, sometimes rebuilding indexes make the difference between a query that never returns to one that returns in 2 seconds. In fact i do not want my users to know the fragmentation by table, but simply thatonce they click the button the have a lower number, i could even use random numbers if the second is less than the first..

Comment: ...Anyway from time to time i could instruct the user that what he is reading is the average of avg_fragmentation_in_percent that with some IT guys it could be ok. So from what you wrote i can somehow see i am on a good but useless path

Comment: `dm_db_index_physical_stats` also offers `page_count` and `fragment_count`, and there's `dm_db_index_usage_stats` for the actual use of the index. With sufficient effort you should be able to determine relative impact of fragmentation for each index, then combine these into an indicator somehow, but it's likely that this effort won't pay off. Effort on devising metrics to determine how "badly" an index needs defragmenting is better spent in the actual maintenance scripts, not independently.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks, write that in an answer and i will accept it

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6044397201516437504
This does not answer the question but it looks like you are looking for this information in order to identify when and how an optimization need to be launched, maybe you can find the approach I took for this script interesting and eventually adapt to your needs or idea.

Comment: Understand when you rebuild your indexes, you are probably clearing out the plan cache for most of your queries since it is an intensive operation... so when you check for performance increase, don't base it off the first run of the query after the index rebuild.

Comment: @P.Lion the link you provided does not work

Comment: @LaBracca link is working form here, maybe you need to login on linkedin first.
Since it is what I do usually on smaller DB I included it here where it is more pertinent as answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914538/maintenance-jobs-in-sql-small-databases/53062483#53062483

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved my dilemma by choosing

```
SELECT
AVG(avg_fragmentation_in_percent) as OverallFragmentationIndicator
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

as indicator.

Moreover i scheduled a monthly execution of `IndexOptimize` and i expect i will not find any corrupted index or need-to-rebuild index in my db for a long time.